# How to display list of documents data from collection named by date?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

//how to display all documents data from all collections? I set the name of each collection by date. This only get the latest data by date.

```
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
    String formatted = formatter.format(now);
    final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;

    QuerySnapshot qn = await db
        .collection('history')
        .document(uid)
        .collection('$formatted')
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
        .getDocuments();

    yield qn.documents;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for a single query to span multiple collections with different names.  The only exception to this is [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) which consider documents across multiple collections **with the exact same name**.

If you want data from multiple collections, you will have to issue a query for each collection, then merge the results in the client app.